# No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0 in FaceDetector.Builder

Tags: android, face-detection, vision, google-play-services

The application throws this error

```
Error Loading module com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0
```

when trying to configure the Google-vision FaceDetector, I am currently working with `'com.google.android.gms: play-services-base: 16.1.0'` and `'com.google.android.gms: play- services-vision: 17.0.2 '`, in **android 7.0** and the version of google play services on the device is **14.7.99**.

this is the logcat output:

```
2019-01-22 16:19:41.682 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.face:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.face:0
2019-01-22 16:19:41.683 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera D/FaceNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load whole module.
2019-01-22 16:19:41.684 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
2019-01-22 16:19:41.689 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1800
2019-01-22 16:19:41.689 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1800
2019-01-22 16:19:41.690 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2019-01-22 16:19:41.695 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.face not found.
2019-01-22 16:19:41.705 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera I/Vision: Loading library libmobile_vision_face.so
2019-01-22 16:19:41.706 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera I/Vision: libmobile_vision_face.so library load status: true
2019-01-22 16:19:41.721 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.face not found.
2019-01-22 16:19:41.726 21333-21333/com.nowfloats.camera I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.face:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.face:0
```

Comment: There's really no solution to this? Updating Google Play Services does not help..

Answer (score -3):

Clear data and cache of google play services from settings.

Comment: Please let us know how to do that.

Comment: Follow below path - > 
1. Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Services -> Storage -> Clear Data & Clear Storage.